# mutliple select dropdown company and save perk and respective company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

here is my code:

Perk not save on `multiple select`,when `multiple true/false`. perk save and habtm working.

```
class Perk < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :perks
end
```

view **perk/new.html.erb**

```
<%= select_tag "company_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, 'id', 'name',@perk.companies.map{ |j| j.id }), :multiple => true %>
<%= f.text_field :name  %>
```

**Controller's code:**

```
def new
  @perk = Perk.new
  respond_with(@perk)
end

def create
  @perk = Perk.new(perk_params)
  @companies = Company.where(:id => params[:company_id])
  @perk << @companies 
  respond_with(@perk)
end
```

Comment: You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows some of the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have included company_id in the perk_params method in your controller. Rails four uses strong pramas this means you need to state the params you are allowing to be set.However it is difficult to say for sure without seeing more of the code.

In your controller you should see a method like this (there may be more options that just :name):

```
def perk_params
  params.require(:perk).permit(:name)
end
```

You should try adding :company_id to it so it looks something like this:

```
def perk_params
  params.require(:perk).permit(:name, :company_id)
end
```

if there are other params int your method leave them in and just added :company_id

EDIT to original answer

The above will only work on a one-to-many or one-to-one because you are using has_and_belongs_to_many you will need to add companies: [] to the end of your params list like this

```
def perk_params
  params.require(:perk).permit(:name, companies: [] )
end
```

or like this

```
def perk_params
  params.require(:perk).permit(:name, companies_ids: [] )
end
```

See these links for more details:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Thanks @mark . I have already permitted company_id to the perks params. but its still not working.

Comment: Sorry I have just re read your question company_id is for a one-to-many or on-to-one relationship. because you are using has_and_belongs_to_many you need to add companies: [] at the end of you lis of params in the  perk_params method

Answer (score 0):

Your `select_tag` should return an array of company_ids:

```
<%= select_tag "company_ids[]", options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, 'id', 'name',@perk.companies.map{ |j| j.id }), :multiple => true %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#691-sending-an-array-of-multiple-options

Then, in your controller, reference the company_ids param:

```
@companies = Company.where(:id => params[:company_ids])
```

(I assume that you've intentionally left out the `@perk.save` call in your create action... Otherwise, that should be included as well. `Model.new` doesn't store the record.)